# Clustering standard errors by a variable in a logistic regression - for graphing interaction plot (R)

Tags: r

I'm running a logistic regression/survival analysis where I cluster standard errors by a variable in the dataset. I'm using R.

Since this is not as straight forward as it is in STATA, I'm using a solution I found in the past : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/miceadds/versions/3.0-16/topics/lm.cluster

As an illustrative example of what I'm talking about:

```
model <- miceadds::glm.cluster(data = data, formula = outcome ~ a + b + c + years + years^2 + years^3, cluster = "cluster.id", family = "binomial")
```

This works well for getting the important values, this produces the coefficients, std. errors (clustered), and z-values. It took me forever just to get at this solution; and even now it is not ideal (like not being able to output to Stargazer). I've explored a lot of the other common suggestions on this issue - such as the Economic Theory solution (https://economictheoryblog.com/2016/12/13/clustered-standard-errors-in-r/); however, this is for lm() and I cannot get it to work for logistic regression.

I'm not beyond just running two models, one with glm() and one with glm.cluster() and replacing the standard errors in stargazer manually.

**My concern** is that I am at a loss as to how I would graph the above function, say if I were to do the following instead:

```
model <- miceadds::glm.cluster(data = data, formula = outcome ~ a*b + c + years + years^2 + years^3, cluster = "cluster.id", family = "binomial")
```

In this case, I want to graph a predicted probability plot to look at the interaction between a*b on my outcome; however, I cannot do so with the glm.cluster() object. I have to do it with a glm() model, but then my confidence intervals are awash.

I've been looking into a lot of the options on clustering standard errors for logistic regression around here, but am at a complete loss.

Has anyone found any recent developments on how to do so in r?
Are there any packages that let you cluster SE by a *variable in the dataset* **and** plot the objects? (Bonus points for interactions)

Any and all insight would be appreciated. Thanks!